# Excel formula for one cell to repeat across a different column (perhaps IF command)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm wanting to look up if a series of values (Column N) fall within a specified range.

Currently trying this:

```
=IF(AND(N:N<=C2,N:N >=L2),"YES","NO")
```

This does not properly work. I want to know if there are any values in Column N that fall between C2 and L2.

Even better, but not necessary, would be to return a value of fit this description (e.g. 1, 2, etc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must this be a single-cell formula? As in, can you add a column next to column N that has something like `=If(And(N23<=$C$2,N23>=$L$2),1,0)`, and then just get a sum of those formulas?

Comment: I have a very long column of C2 and L2 (10,000s) ... So, if I really need to do this across N:N

Comment: My previous statement may be confusing ... I have lots of comparisons. I want to know if there are any values in Column N, that fall between ranges Column C and Column L (e.g. C2 and L2, C3 and L3, etc). Thanks.

Comment: @P-D you should edit your question with the clarifications you provide in your comments-this will make your question higher quality and easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(N:N,"<="&C2,N:N,">="&L2)
```

This will count the number of cells in N:N that are less than or equal to C2, and that are more than or equal to L2